# Sticky sidebar javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css

How do you make a sticky vertical sidebar with stopper, but *without* jQuery? Are there any snippets/plugins? I don't need it to support older browsers.

I don't mean just position: fixed, it must stay in the same place and then start being sticky (fixed) when you've scrolled past a certain point. It must then stop following at the stop point.

Like http://stickyjs.com, but NOT jQuery. There are many jQuery plugins available.

Answer (score 7):

Basically it's as easy as this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var sticky = document.getElementById('stickynav');
    if( document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop > 240)
        sticky.className = "stuck";
    else sticky.className = "";
};
```

Then just define styles in the `.stuck` class that add things like `position:fixed` to the element.

Comment: What a nice simple solution. OP in production consider adding an event listener and if you want it to have other classes too slice the className to an array and remove/add to it

Comment: This solution has a lot of problems. It's exactly what I'm doing right now. The jQuery plugins have dozens of lines of code, why would they make a plugin if it was that simple?

* This solution doesn't have a stopper,
you can't have variable height document headers as offset is hard coded, freaks out if the the sidebar has height longer than the content and doesn't let you scroll to the bottom, will sometimes have your sidebar float higher than it was supposed to

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt that doesn't require `position: fixed` changes, uses the element-document distance as reference and let's you scroll to the bottom:

```
var node = document.getElementById('side'),  // your element
    nodeOffs = node.offsetTop,               // distance relative to its parent
    parent = node;

// loop through parents to determine the distance relative to the document top
while(parent = parent.offsetParent)
  if(parent.offsetTop)
    nodeOffs += parent.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){    

  // current scroll position relative to the body
  var scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;

  if(scrollPos > nodeOffs){

    // don't do anything if the elements height is larger than the
    // remaining scroll content height (distance including)
    if(scrollPos < (document.body.scrollHeight - node.clientHeight - nodeOffs))
      node.style.top = (scrollPos - nodeOffs) + 'px';

  }else{
      node.style.top = '0px';
  }

});
```

It's likely that this won't handle all possible cases (it doesn't take into account margins for example). That's why there's a plugin that you should use it if you don't want to tweak the js yourself....

[(test)](http://jsfiddle.net/GDEpM/)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do it with shorter JS.

```js
const stickyDiv = document.querySelector(".sticky");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  stickyDiv.style.top = window.pageYOffset + "px";
});
```

```css
.left {
  position: relative;
}
.sticky {
  position: absolute;
}

  /* below is unecessary CSS just to demo the page */
.left {
  width:40%;
  float:left;
}
.right {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 3000px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="left">
      <article class="sticky">
        <h2>Sticky sidebar title here</h2>
        <p>Text here</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <article>
        <h2>Regular page here</h2>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats">
        <p>Regular page content here.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/vYYxvza

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and that it is asking for a JavaScript solution BUT, as the main idea here is to get a sticky sidebar working, I have to share that there is a pure CSS solution that works just as expected:

```
.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Just apply that `sticky` class to your sidebar elements and that will work.

That will, for sure, save you all a lot of time and effort.

REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky